# how to update a datagridview on a Parent form from a Child Form C#

Tags: sql-server, winforms, c#-4.0, devexpress, xtragrid

I'm quite a new C# programmer,it has been a month that ive started using C#, so far so good i might say, but im curently dealing with a simple situation , but i still dont get it to work , there is the scenario :

I've 2 forms a Parent and a Child  , the parent contains a Xtragrid control and a button which opens the second form and load the textBoxes in the second form with values , the second has a button to update the values in case of any changes . but i still dont get it to work , I've the following error :

> MUST DECLARE A SCALAR VARIABLE at @ID

I understood the cause of the probleme but i just cant fix it ,ive have done some researches to sort myself out but i still didnt manage to make it work
 the last line

`da.updatecommand.parameters.addwithvalues("ID@",ds.tables["tblLesseeYW"].Rows[LesseeYW.Position][0];`

I have done it but it is not working( LesseeYW which is my binding source object but it doesnt exit in the current context nor the dataset which is understandable 
 : there is the code need help pleaese

```
// This the class ive created to retrieve all Columns from the SQl server data base
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace YoungWoman
 {
   public static class GetRowData
{

   public static int LesseeId;
   public static byte LesseePic;
   public static string LesseeName;
   public static string LesseeLastName;
   public static string PassportNo;
   public static string IDNo;
   public static DateTime BirthDate;
   public static string Gender;
   public static string Country;
   public static string City;
   public static string Province;
   public static string LesseePostalCode;
   public static string MobileNo;
   public static string HomePhoneNo;
   public static string TutorName;
   public static string TutorLastName;
   public static string AddressTutor;
   public static string AddressLessee;
   public static string TutorPhoneNo;
   public static string TutorEmail;




     }
   }


  // the parent form 


     namespace YoungWoman
   {

     public partial class Lessee2 : UserControl
    {
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
       DataView dv ;
      SqlDataAdapter daLessee = new SqlDataAdapter();
      SqlDataAdapter daReservation = new SqlDataAdapter();
      BindingSource LesseeYW = new BindingSource();

       BindingSource ReservationCenterYW = new BindingSource();

       SqlConnection conne = SqlCoonectionSEtup.GetConnection;

// the button that opens the Child Form

    private void EditLesseeFrm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Lesseefrm Lessee = new Lesseefrm(Utils.Formtype.edit, 1);
        Lessee.LesseeEventHandler += new EventHandler(RefreshLesseeGrid);

        GetRowData.LesseeId = Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue    (gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "LesseeId"));
        GetRowData.LesseeName = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "LesseeName"));
        GetRowData.LesseeLastName = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle,"LesseeLastName"));
        GetRowData.PassportNo = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle,"PassportNo"));
        GetRowData.Gender = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "Gender"));
        GetRowData.Province = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "Province"));
        GetRowData.BirthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "BirthDate"));
        GetRowData.City = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "City"));
        GetRowData.Country = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "Country"));
        GetRowData.MobileNo = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "MobileNo"));
        GetRowData.HomePhoneNo = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "HomePhoneNo"));
        GetRowData.IDNo = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "IDNo"));
        GetRowData.AddressLessee = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "AddressLessee"));
        GetRowData.AddressTutor = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "AddressTutor"));
        GetRowData.LesseePostalCode = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "LesseePostalCode"));
        GetRowData.TutorName = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "TutorName"));
        GetRowData.TutorLastName = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "TutorLastName"));
        GetRowData.TutorPhoneNo = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "TutorPhoneNo"));
        GetRowData.TutorEmail = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "TutorEmail"));


        Lessee.ShowDialog();
    }



     ( // Child LOad_form if form type == Edit )


          if (formtype == Formtype.edit && Lesseeid > 0)
            {



                LesseeIdtextEdit.Enabled = false;
                ClearBtnlayoutControlItem26.Visibility =    DevExpress.XtraLayout.Utils.LayoutVisibility.Never;
                SaveBtn.Text = "&Edit";
                SaveBtn.Image = Resources.brush_16;
                this.Text = string.Format(" Edit Lessee Information - YW Residence ");

                LesseeIdtextEdit.Text = Convert.ToInt32(GetRowData.LesseeId).ToString();
                txtName.Text = GetRowData.LesseeName;
                txtLAstname.Text = GetRowData.LesseeLastName;
                txtPassport.Text = GetRowData.PassportNo;
                txtID.Text = GetRowData.IDNo;
                GendercomboBoxEdit.SelectedItem = GetRowData.Gender;
                DobdateEdit.DateTime = GetRowData.BirthDate;
                CountrycomboBoxEdit.SelectedItem = GetRowData.Country;
                txtProvince.Text = GetRowData.Province;
                txtCity.Text = GetRowData.City;
                txtPostalCode.Text = GetRowData.LesseePostalCode;
                LesseememoEdit1.Text = GetRowData.AddressLessee;
                txtMobile.Text = GetRowData.MobileNo;
                txtHomePhone.Text = GetRowData.HomePhoneNo;
                txtTutorName.Text = GetRowData.TutorName;
                txttutorLastname.Text = GetRowData.TutorLastName;
                tutorAddresstxt.Text = GetRowData.AddressTutor;
                txtTutorMobile.Text = GetRowData.TutorPhoneNo;
                txtEmail.Text = GetRowData.TutorEmail;



            }



     public event System.EventHandler LesseeEventHandler;

     private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

       if (formtype == Formtype.edit && Lesseeid > 0)
            {

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                PicBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                byte[] Pic_arr = new byte[ms.Length];
                ms.Position = 0;
                ms.Read(Pic_arr, 0, Pic_arr.Length);

                try
                {

                    da.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand(" UPDATE LesseeYW SET LesseePic = @image , LesseeName = @Name, LesseeLastName = @Last , PassportNo = @pass,IDNo = @Number, BirthDate =@birth ,Gender = @gender , Country =@country,LesseePostalCode = @Postal,City = @city , Province = @province,MobileNo = @Mobile,HomePhoneNo = @phone,TutorName = @tutor,TutorLastName=@Tlast,AddressTutor = @line1,AddressLessee=@line2,TutorPhoneNo = @Tphone,TutorEmail =@Temail WHERE LesseeId = @ID ", conne);
                    da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", Pic_arr);
                    da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
                    da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last", txtLAstname.Text);
                    da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", txtPassport.Text);
                    da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", txtID.Text);
                    da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birth", DobdateEdit.DateTime);
                    da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", GendercomboBoxEdit.SelectedItem.ToString());
                    da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", CountrycomboBoxEdit.SelectedItem.ToString());
                    da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postal", txtPostalCode.Text);
                    da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", txtCity.Text);
                    da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@province", txtProvince.Text);
                    da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", txtMobile.Text);
                    da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", txtHomePhone.Text);
                    da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tutor", txtTutorName.Text);
                    da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tlast", txttutorLastname.Text);
                    da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@line1", tutorAddresstxt.Text);
                    da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@line2", LesseememoEdit1.Text);
                    da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tphone", txtTutorMobile.Text);
                    da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Temail", txtEmail.Text);
                   //da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID"




                    da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conne.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Lessee Details Updated ", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    this.Close();

                }

                catch (Exception Ex)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

at first you should program more objective. Dont declare all variables of your class as public static. You should make them private. To get acces you have to declare Properties.

Like this:

```
private string name;

public string Name
{
  get {return name;}
  set {name = value;}
}
```

if you have an ID you can easily make it read-only and noone from "outside" can modify it but everyone can read.

```
private int leeseId;

public int LeeseID
{
  get{return leeseId;}
}
```

So you use "getter/setter" to offer your class properties. Further not all your variables should named leese... Just name it id,name,city,pic etc. In your form you create an Object from your class. You can name this object Leese.

```
private Leese leese = new Leese();
leese.id = ???
leese.name = ???
```

Much more readable.

```
da.updatecommand.parameters.addwithvalues("ID@",ds.tables["tblLesseeYW"].Rows[LesseeYW.Position][0];
```

You wrote "ID@" but it should be "@ID". And if you build your class as i descripe at top you can use property:

```
da.updatecommand.parameters.addwithvalues("@ID", leese.Id);
```

i hope that help you.

Comment: thank so much as i told you im still new , i will try to program more objective, i really appreciate that .